# Tomcat does not load HTTPS sites after a while

Tags: tomcat, ssl, configuration, https

The http and https site we created can be accessed after restarting the server (when the user accesses the http site, it forwards them to https). Eventually, (after a day or 2) the http site still redirects the user to https site (meaning the server is till up and works). However the https site does not load. Even if we directly access the https site.

Has this happened to anyone? How can I fix this? What do I need to check to identify the cause?

Comment: Post the OS that you have deployed Tomcat to. Give more detail on exactly what occurs when the HTTPS site does not load. Add log file errors and errors seen on the client side.

Comment: Thread dumps are your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Check the log files.

Use [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/index.html) to monitor the state of the JVM on which Tomcat is running.

Investigate monitoring [JMX data exposed by Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html#Introduction).

Consider monitor incoming TCP/IP connections

Ideally, attempting to reproduce this behaviour in a staging environment by hammering the site with traffic would be useful as this would be a safer place to do the above monitoring.